# MySQL replication on slave server Broken/Stopped without error

Tags: mysql, replication

(Hi; sorry for my English)
My question is: how can I restart MySQL replication on a slave server.
At first sight everything seems to be normal but when I check with

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

besides Relay_Log_Space, Read_Master_Log_Pos and Seconds_Behind_Master which
continue to increase. Other data remain fixed for several days.
I tried STOP/START SLAVE; but nothing has changed.

```
root@localhost [mysql]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: x.x.x.x
                  Master_User: slave_replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000103
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 197827259
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 149672940
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000029
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 305160334
              Relay_Log_Space: 65277287216
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 1724670
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 3464562
                  Master_UUID: 727b7e74-325f-11e6-9b54-faa1cd739fa9
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
```

Comment: I see you have 65GB in Relay logs. Question: Did you perform a `LOAD DATA INFILE` on the master about 20 days ago ???

Comment: Thanks for your response and the answer is no!

Answer (score 1):

Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event...

Suggests that it's working on a large event. If you have MIXED or Row based binary logging and have changed a large amount of data on the master you might end up with a large event or series of large events. Use the mysqlbinlog tool to see what's going on with your relaylog. The master might show a concentration of binary logs over a small period of time (on the filesystem)

Comment: Actually I changed the binlog_format from STATEMENT to MIXED about 20 days ago...

Comment: have you checked what eroomydna told you ?